# Detecting keystrokes without textboxes?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, window, internet-explorer-9

I have to use javascript to make links instead of  for several unimportant reasons, and I want for it to behave like  even though im not using it. Not the affects thats easy, but I want to be able to hold down shift while clicking to open a new window and to open it in a new tab if they are holding down ctrl. How would I do this? Also, it has to be compatible with IE9.

[edit] Also, this is going to be in an iframe

Comment: Basically, Im trying to add key combinations.

Comment: Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/V8yzF/show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want something like this:

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/MXuVY/3/

**JavaScript**

```
var ctrlPressed = false;
$('#link').click(function () {
    var link = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';
    if (ctrlPressed) {
        window.open(link,'_blank');
    } else {
        window.location = link;
    }
    return false;
});
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 17) {
        ctrlPressed = true;
    }
});
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 17) {
        ctrlPressed = false;
    }
});
```

​

**HTML**

```
<span id="link">Link to stackoverflow</span>​
```

​**Version without jQuery**

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/MXuVY/6/

**JavaScript**

```
function addEvent(el, eType, fn, uC) {
    if (el.addEventListener) {
        el.addEventListener(eType, fn, uC);
        return true;
    } else if (el.attachEvent) {
        return el.attachEvent('on' + eType, fn);
    } else {
        el['on' + eType] = fn;
    }
}

var ctrlPressed = false,
    a = document.getElementById('link'),
    link = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';

addEvent(a, 'click', function () {
    if (ctrlPressed) {
        window.open(link,'_blank');
    } else {
        window.location = link;
    }
    return false;
});
addEvent(document, 'keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 17) {
        ctrlPressed = true;
    }
});
addEvent(document, 'keyup', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 17) {
        ctrlPressed = false;
    }
});
```

​

Comment: on jsfiddle, it says "for security reasons framing is not allowed; click ok to remove the frames"

Comment: nevermind it works fine. But do you have a version without jquery?

Comment: Here is the version without jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/MXuVY/6/.
I'll also add this to my answer.

Comment: Also don't forget to execute the code after the span element have been loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Bind a keystroke event listener to window or document and use it's callback function to do whatever you need.

If you use jquery, its a bit easier to make a more reliable keystroke listener, imho. http://blog.cnizz.com/2008/10/27/javascript-key-listener/

Comment: will this work if my window is in an iframe that doesnt have focus?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't know the answer to that question. You can try it and let us know if it works. My guess is that it would work.

Comment: No, the iframe won't be able to receive keypress events if it doesn't have focus.

Comment: yeah i just tested it and it doesnt

Answer (score 0):

So, this is what you want: [***`http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/V8yzF/show`***](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/V8yzF/show)

```
$("a").click(function(ev) {
    if (ev.ctrlKey) {                     //If ctrl
        window.open(this.attr("href"));
        retrun false;
    } else if (ev.shiftKey) {            //If shift
        window.open(this.attr("href"),"_blank", "width=400,height=300");
        retrun false;
    } else {                             //If nothing
        //do nothing
    }
});​
```